# Retrieve deeply nested Firebase data in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my first question here on SO but I'll try to be most precise. I've went through all possible topics but didn't find an answer. I have a database like on the picture. I'm trying to retrieve "costAmount" from all entries and make a sum of it and then show it in Navigation Bar. The problem is that I don't know how to access this level of data. Any suggestions?

Database structure

[image]

This is what I came up with.

```
func showTitle() {
    let title = UILabel()
    var sum = 0
    title.text = "\(sum)"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = title

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users/\(currentUser!)/cars/\((car?.identifier)!)/Costs/costAmount").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let cost = snapshot.value as? String {
            guard let totalCost = Int(cost) else {return}
            sum += totalCost
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: A few things: 1) Welcome to SO. 2) [Screenshots are Evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Don't use them. Please include code and structures as TEXT so we don't have to retype them in answers. 3) Your Firebase structure may be too deep. 4) The question is unclear; are you totaling the costAmount for a specific car or for all cars within a node or for all cars in the database? 5) You have uneeded duplicate data, you don't need to store a child node that contains the same value as the key to the node.

Comment: No screenshots ever, noted down ;) I wasn't perfectly clear so let me explain: first I have a user who can login/register. Then, when car is added "car.identifier" is added se every cost, service, bills, mileage, etc, can be identified and show data for right car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I wasn't perfectly clear at the beginning but thanks to your answers I came up with a solution.

```
func showTitle() {
    let title = UILabel()
    var sum = 0.0
    title.text = "\(sum)"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = title
    title.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    title.textAlignment = .center

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()


ref.child("Users/\(currentUser!)/cars/\((car?.identifier)!)/Costs").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    let costObject = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    let costAmount = costObject?["costAmount"] as! String?
    if let numericalCost = Double(costAmount!) {
        sum += numericalCost

        print(numericalCost)

    }

    title.text = "\(sum)"

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an apple developer but I will try to help:

Okay it seems that you have users that login to your app and you save their uids under users node.

Assuming that I am analysing this right:

**You have 3 levels of nested (random ids).**

level 1: Is the uid of the users.

level 2: Is the id of the cars per each user.

level 3: Is the id of the cost per each car.

If you can reference these 3 ids you will read the needed data.

level 1: this one is easy if your users are logged in its just the auth uid.

level 2: this one must be referenced by you when maybe you click a car in of a certain user.

level 3: same as level 2 you must keep a reference.

now the code:

```
//database reference
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()

//user id (level 1)
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

//(level 2)
let carID = ...... its up to you to reference this
//(level 3)  
let CostID = ...... its up to you to reference this  


//read the costAmount

ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("cars").child(carID).child("Costs").child(CostID)
   .child("costAmount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  // Get value
  let costAmount= snapshot.value as? Int


  // ...
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: You missed a couple of parent nodes in the description. i.e. under cars you have the id key for each car and then within that you have the repairs (I assume) then within each repair you have a costAmount. I don't think that's cost of each car, I think it's cost of each repair *for for each car*

Comment: Oh. And while you code is very nice and works, it will only get a single cost. The OP specifically asked *I'm trying to retrieve "costAmount" from all entries*.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for help. I tried @svi.data solution but as Jay said - it only shows a single cost. That helped me to coma up with solution though ;)